# Mocha not invoking the before method, causing stacktrace at line surpassing multiple uninvoked tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

A stacktrace is occurring on line 261, an error that wouldn't of occurred if the 'before' method was invoked before all the tests.

I've tried restructuring the tests, using `async` and `await`, as well as attempting to debug the test cases to see why the before method is not being invoked. I've read and reread the documentation on mocha. I'm miffed on how to resolve this issue.

test.js:

```
    tables
        .create({ <-- line 261.
          golden_white: {
            schema: {
              id: "int auto_increment primary key",
              first_name: "varchar(20) not null",
              last_name: "varchar(20) not null"
            }
          }
        })
```

The snippet of code containing the line that is throwing the stacktrace.

test.js - before method:

```
  let docker = new Docker({ socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock" });
  let container = null;
  let tables = null;
  const databaseName = "goldpresi_tablesTest_database";

  before(function(done) {
    docker.container
      .create({
        Image: "mariadb:latest",
        Env: ["MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwd"]
      })
      .catch(err => done(err))
      .then(c => {
        container = c;
      })
      .then(c => c.status())
      .then(status => {
        pool = mysql2.createPool({
          username: "root",
          password: "password",
          host: `${status.data.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}`
        });

        pool
          .query(`create database ${databaseName}`)
          .then(() => pool.query(`use database ${databaseName}`))
          .then(() => {
            tables = new Tables(pool);
            done()})
          .catch(err => done(err));
      });
  });
```

The stacktrace:

```
/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of null
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/backend/test/build/test.js:264:10)
    at Object.create (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:140:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/backend/test/build/test.js:261:5)
    at Object.create (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:140:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/backend/test/build/test.js:260:3)
    at Object.create (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:140:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/backend/test/build/test.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:330:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:327:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:804:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:207:16)
    at exports.runMocha (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:300:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:296:3)
    at Object.runCommand (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1104:24)
    at Object.parse (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:63:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/duke/Documents/Development/Web Development/higher_and_further_courses_web_app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

Test.js: https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/Goldpresi-Website-Application/blob/master/backend/test/build/test.js
Tables.js: https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/Goldpresi-Website-Application/blob/master/backend/src/scripts/dataManager/tables.js

I expected the before method located in the parent 'describe' to be invoked, then for all the other test cases to procedurally be invoked, with the expected text being printed in the console.